# php get byte length of object, for header

Tags: php, soap, content-length

I need to set php `header("Content-Length: length")`, where length is a byte value. Right now I have arbitrarily set it to 1 megabyte due to the variable size of my post request, but I want to dynamically generate this so that there isn't erroneous data.

How can I get the byte size of my object before I send it to the server. I am making a `soapCall` so I have to set the header before I do that call, instead of adding a parameter to `curl` or something.

Comment: count() for byte arrays.

Comment: soap doesn't need you to set it's header. If it's SOAP use PHP SOAP extension and it takes cares of all, if it's CURL, so what is use of soapCall api here?

Comment: Consider using output buffering and use [`ob_get_length`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-length.php)

Comment: Why do you need the `Content-Length` header at all?  Your server should automatically go back to chunked encoding.

Comment: @VahidFarahmand I believe you but the api I am communicating with certainly does return different things if I set Content-Length or not manually.

Comment: @deceze it is a struct containing simple data types like integers and strings, but may contain other structs (also with simple data types)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following (there ought to be something better, I know):

```
$before = memory_get_usage(TRUE);
$objectClone = clone $yourObject;
$after = memory_get_usage(TRUE);
$objectSize = $after - $before;  #size of your object
$objectClone = $null; #dispose of clone
```

Comment: uhmmmm, somebody smack me to wake me up. this could be good I guess since php isn't asynchronous so there wouldn't be other things going on simultaneous that might alter the outcome

Comment: Yeah, I wouldn't want to do this in a multi-threaded or asynchronous environment.  It's gross.  PHP should have a better facility.

Comment: As it is, it's the only way I'm aware of doing this.  Anyone else?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with SOAP, so forgive me if this doesn't apply to your situation.

I had to solve this problem not too long ago for a personal project of mine, where I dynamically generated and streamed large ZIPs to the user. My solution was to precompute the size of the object by generating it once and recording its size. The drawback to this solution is that the size needs to be recomputed if the contents of the object change, but if you have a finite number of objects whose sizes don't change often, it might work for you.

The code I used looks something like this:

```
ob_start();
$zip_length = 0;
$zip = new ZipStream();
foreach ($files as $virtual_path => $file_path) {
    $zip->add_file_from_path($virtual_path, $file_path);
    $zip_length += strlen(ob_get_contents());
    ob_clean(); /* prevent excessive memory usage */
}
$zip->finish();
$zip_length += strlen(ob_get_contents());
ob_end_clean();
/* Store $zip_length somewhere */
```

If this is too general for your purposes, perhaps consider specifying what "objects" you're sending to the user.